# UK visitor visa: I cannot see visitor option under "reason for visit" in VFS global website

Tags: visas, uk, vfs-global

I am trying to purchase priority service through vfs for my standard visa application in USA. However, no option related to visitor visa under "reason for visit" box. How shall I proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to book an appointment? 
Happened to me also, so turns out their site is buggy and have to call them to schedule the appointment in that case.

Comment: What is the phone number for your to call them?

Comment: @Piyush Can you please share which number did you use to call? We are 4 to 5 people waiting for this!! :) Btw, I'm from San Francisco, California

Comment: I am not from USA so not sure of phone number but you can easily find number of the particular vfs cente in your city.As I said I had trouble of similar nature last year for UK visa on their site and I had also opted for priority service. Maybe I should have commented rather than answer so sorry.

Comment: having the same issue. What number should I call ?

Comment: I am confused on the issue you are facing.Depending on your city phone number will change(so I can't help). Search it on their website or google that should solve the issue. Could you elaborate on why you are not able to locate the number ?