# UK Visa - VFSGlobal issue

Tags: visas, uk

I have filled the form and paid the application fee for a standard visitor visa on GOV.UK website. I am an Indian national planning to visit the UK for tourism. When I visit the VFSglobal website to book an appointment, it does not list "Standard Visitor Visa" as an option. Kindly help.[image: Screenshot of VFS Global visa options]

Comment: I am pretty sure we have seen this question or one very much like it recently. I can not find it right now. Try a different browser or wait a day or two are solutions that often work.

Comment: @Willeke This one maybe? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137872/uk-visitor-visa-i-cannot-see-visitor-option-under-reason-for-visit-in-vfs-glo

Comment: I think that is the one I remembered, not really the same but near enough to be useful.